# Original SQL script now invalid according to Flyway

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

We have a Spring boot application that has been in production for a while. We use Flyway to manage database migrations. I just upgraded to Spring boot 2.5.4 from 2.4.5 which brings with it an upgrade to Flyway 7.7.3.

When executing all the migrations in a fresh local environment, the migration now fails due to a syntax issue with this comment:

```
---*********************---
-- ** AUDITING TABLES ** --
---*********************---
```

I imagine this won't be an issue in environments which have already executed this migration but what is the best way to fix this for new environments with a fresh database given that the original file cannot be edited due to checksum comparison on migration?

My current versioning just includes a major version i.e. V2, V3 etc. My thinking is to get rid of V2 (the script with the issue) and introduce V2.1 which would be an exact copy of V2 with the erroneous comment section removed. I would then set both `ignoreMissingMigrations` and `ignoreIgnoredMigrations` to `true`

Does this sound like the right way to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using MySQL 5.7. Initial tests indicate that the approach I mentioned in the OP seems to be working. Will most likely stick with this approach unless someone suggests a better alternative.

Comment: what is the encoding characterset of you sql files ? the lower versions of flyway didn't have problem with that but all your sql files should be UTF-8 or US7ASCII or if it's different you have to specify the encoding yourself: 
https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the script and then executing `flyway repair` would be the ideal solution - this would rectify the checksums.

Assuming this option is not available for some reason (it would be helpful to know what that is in case we can fix it!), the above sounds correct. `ignoreMissingMigrations` means your old deployments won't object to V2 not being there, and `ignoreIgnoredMigrations` means they won't object to V2.1 being present. The downside is that these ignores may not be valid in the longer term - so they won't, for example, catch a later script that goes missing unintentionally.

Comment: Thanks @Julia. You're probably right that `flyway repair` is the way to go. I did come across that but it seemed like the more invasive option and wasn't 100% sure of potential side-effects. I haven't deployed to any live environments yet so I have time to revert to that option.